# Is it necessary to move OpenFileDialog code for opening the files and put it into a separate method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to separate the code inside my `Add button click event` from the code in order to make my code looks more arranged.
this is my code before these changes (i am using BackgroundWorker in order to avoid my GUI to freeze because every file that I am choosing need to open process and check if this is file OK before add this file into my Listbox):

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Stream stream;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileSelected();
        if (openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 0)
            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileNames[0]);

        ListboxFile lbf = new ListboxFile();
        lbf.OnFileAddEvent += lbf_OnFileAddEvent;

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        int numberOfFiles = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames.Length;
                        using (stream)
                        {
                            lbf.checkFile(file);
                            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileNames[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        };

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            (s3, e3) =>
            {
                //update my gui
            });

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

and this is after the changes:

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileSelected();
    }
}

private void fileSelected()
{
    if (openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 0)
        lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileNames[0]);

    ListboxFile lbf = new ListboxFile();
    lbf.OnFileAddEvent += lbf_OnFileAddEvent;

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            System.IO.Stream stream;
            try
            {
                if ((stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    int numberOfFiles = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames.Length;
                    using (stream)
                    {
                        lbf.checkFile(file);
                        lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileNames[0]);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            //update my gui
        });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

So, what I did is necessary ?
Maybe something else was better ?

Comment: you are better of asking this kind of questions at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @yvytty can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you make it less readable by only adding more lines of code.

I would suggest you to:

1. handle all OpenFileDialog related code in your click event handler
2. pass a list of selected files to a method named `CheckAndShowFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)`.
3. let CheckFile return a bool instead of throwing an Exception.
4. Check file and add to view in one step foreach file to give the user a sense of progress.